# Why is Topological Sorting to find the shortest path O(V+E)

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, topological-sort

I am confused to why topological sorting for shortest path is Big-O of O(V+E). 
Here is the algorithm:

```
1. Topologically sort G into L;
2. Set the distance to the source to 0;
3. Set the distances to all other vertices to infinity;
4. For each vertex u in L
5.    - Walk through all neighbors v of u;
6.    - If dist(v) > dist(u) + w(u, v) 
7.       - Set dist(v) <- dist(u) + w(u, v);
```

Seem to me it's O(V*E) rather than O(V+E) because it has 2 nested for loops. but according to Wikipedia it's O(V+E), Am I missing something here ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Application_to_shortest_path_finding

Comment: You are visiting each edge exactly once (in the inner loop), and you are using each vertex in L as the current vertex u exactly once. By assumption (since you have to be able to topologically sort the graph) your digraph is acyclic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that the edges are directed, so the same edge is never considered for more than one vertex. Despite the nested loop, you end up looking at each vertex and each edge exactly once.